# How Do I Save 3d View as a Wireframe Image? (Blender Render)

Tags: rendering, opengl, wireframe

I have some objects that I want to save their wireframe view as an image file.

Someone told me to use the OpenGL render active viewport button on the 3d viewer's menu header, but I just get an error message saying *Failed to create OpenCL off-screen buffer, unknown* when I try that.

I was also told to press F3 to save it that way, but that just gives me a history menu.

Then I was told to go to the file menu and "save as render", but I have no such option.

Can anybody who knows what they're talking about please help me?

Comment: You should tell more about the OpenGL error you got. Because there shouldn't be any error. Or your video card hasn't yet been driven correctly, which means you need to install the driver for hte card.

Comment: The error was "Fialed to create OpenCL off-screen buffer, unknown".

Comment: Apparently, I don't have a video card, since nothing shows up when I look at my system information.

Comment: So back to the question.... How do I save a ireframe display as an image?

Comment: There are so many solutions: OpenGL, Freestyle, UV layout texture, Cycles material, wireframe modifier.... Just search it in this site. There are already many duplicated questions.

Comment: Points are taken by users (not necessarily 'admins') when you don't fully articulate your questions and don't provide enough information. For example you state that you get an error but you don't tell us what message you get and that is obviously needed information to help. Anyway check answer bellow, see if it helps

Comment: I decided to just do a screenshot, since I don't want to go on hunting expeditions to try to solve this the proper way. You should be taking away points for that previous comment not supplying more info on how to use the many solutions they listed. Apparently, I can't do that myself, so something isn't right here.

Answer (score 1):

Must be an integrated Intel graphics card, those are known to cause trouble. You should look into solving that problem first as there is no other way of capturing OpenGL viewport wireframe.

Anyway alternatives are

1. If you are using Blender Internal render create a new material and at the top of the *Properties Window > Material Tab* change it to *Wire* type. Optionally turn on  *Shading > Shadeless*

[image: Blender Internal Wireframe]

2. If you´re using cycles create a new material and add a *Wireframe* node as mix mask between two other shaders. Combine them as desired to achieve whatever visual you want.

[image: Cycles Wireframe Shader]

Comment: I'm just going to use a screenshot. One button press is far better than going to all the trouble of setting up nodes or materials. I do believe that I have no graphics card other than what was built in. Nothing shows up in my system info.