# Can I export a jpeg or something similar?

Tags: export

I am **very** new to blender and am really excited to have found this amazing world of Blender and all of its beautiful people and possibilities. I am trying to capture an image of my projects to record and share progress. Can I export a simple jpeg or something similar? Or do I need to take a screenshot? And can that be done within Blender?
  Thanks for your time And Answers... and possibly a better solution to my query.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56440/how-do-i-save-3d-view-as-a-wireframe-image-blender-render/

Comment: Probably what you want to do is "render an image".
In the 3D Viewport, have lights, a camera and materials set up and then hit F12.
You will see that the image needs some time to fully calculate. Afterwards you can save that image on your harddrive.
Just google "Blender Cycles rendering"